# Why are 2.4 GHz amplifiers costly while RF amplifier IC's are cheap?

Tags: pcb, amplifier, rf

A lot of 2.4 GHz amplifiers on eBay are sold for $30-50, but the amplifying chips are available on Digikey < $1. Why? The PCB's are two layers and other SMD components are quite cheap too, then why such a high price? Is there anything sophisticated in it?

Comment: Because someone that knew what they were doing made a module, so people that don't have a clue can use the technology, and as the Joker said, "If you're good at something, never do it for free."

Comment: The chips cost a lot of money to develop, and then this is recovered by selling massive quantities. The amplifier people on eBay do not move that kind of volume.

Comment: Moreover, if the chips cost $30, then the amplifier would have to be $300 or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to have an honest answer about this kind of question is to ask yourself: if you wanted to build these devices yourself, sell them and make a living of it, how much would you want to be paid ?

You have to consider raw material price and how many devices you can build in a day. You will also need some tools, the more advanced your tools are, the bigger your daily production will be. But you will have to buy those tools first. How many $30 amplifiers devices do you need to sell before you can make a pick and place machine profitable?

Long story short, the final price of a product is not just the sum of its components price.

Comment: Many other electronic products are available on ebay for little more than or even for less than the components cost from avaulable sources. Good examples are various boost and buck converters / LED drivers etc which are astoundingly well priced. | One possible factors is that RF involves much black magic and blood sweat and tears in producing an apparently simple design which is in fact extremely critical wrt layout etc. And volumes are perhaps lower. And 'what the market will bear' may be higher than for LED drivers.